# Hibernate many-to-many with additional Id column

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm in desperation with my problem. Seems I try everything. I have to create entity (`User`) with Map of Set of another entities (`Map<Subsystem,Set<Role>>`). I think, I create good schema in database (on pic.)[image: Database representation]

There are many-to-many relationship between `Subsystem` and `Role` with additional `id` column, that used in `User` to get desired `Map<Subsystem,Set<Role>>`.

I get half working solution with spectial entity `SubsystemRole`, where I placed `id`. Also I create method in `User` `Map<Subsystem, Set<Role>> subsystemRoleSetMap()`.

But I faced problem, when I edit any field in some `Subsystem` (or `Role`), Hibernate tries to delete all rows with this `Subsystem` in `subsystem_role` table, and insert it again with fresh generated ids.

So, how to force Hibernate to update `subsystem_role` without deleting?
May be this article contains solution https://giannigar.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/mapping-a-many-to-many-join-table-with-extra-column-using-jpa/#comments, but it don't works for me.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).